# Rails 4 - yandex mail is not sending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

In rails 4.2.4, I am using `gem 'rails_config'` for emails feature. In development environment all mails are sending properly but in test environment it is showing an error like `Net::SMTPFatalError (553 5.7.1 Sender address rejected: not owned by auth user.):`

In setup_mail.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
 :address => "smtp.yandex.ru",
 :port => 465,
 :domain => "yandex.ru",
 :authentication => :login,
 :user_name => "ssstest@yandex.com",
 :password => "pwd567@",
 :ssl=> true,
 :enable_starttls_auto=> true,
 :tls=> true
}
```

In user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
   default from: "ssstest@yandex.com"
   ...
end
```

Server log's output is,

```
 D, [2016-05-06T06:24:25.089270 #23566] DEBUG -- : 
 Devise::Mailer#confirmation_instructions: processed outbound mail in 954.3ms
 I, [2016-05-06T06:24:26.500832 #23566]  INFO -- : 
 Sent mail to sample_demo@yopmail.com (1408.8ms)
 D, [2016-05-06T06:24:26.501240 #23566] DEBUG -- : Date: Fri, 06 May 2016 06:24:25 +0000
 From: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com
 Reply-To: please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com
 To: sample_demo@yopmail.com
 Message-ID: <572c389917f09_5c0e10bb99411990@ip-10-65-178-51.mail>
 Subject: Confirmation instructions
 Mime-Version: 1.0
 Content-Type: text/html;
  charset=UTF-8
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

How can I fix this issue? Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error log indicates, please change the from email address inside config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.mailer_sender = 'ssstest@yandex.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
port: 465
authentication: login
smtp_enable_starttls_auto: true
smtp_openssl_verify_mode: true
```

As mentioned here

https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html#yandex

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp` in the `environments/test.rb` ? And it is not a good practice to store usernames and passwords right in the email setup. Store them as environment variables.